# SSRS Pivot Expression Inside Stored Procedure with HashTemp Not Running

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

While Working With SSRS, Today, i got 2 Problems 1 is Still remain Unsolved and Im going to Post Another Freaking Problem :) Well, Problem is : I've an Stored Procedure, Which Create an #Temp and Finally Use that data with PIVOT Expression. And, Stored Procedure itself runs Fine inside SSMS and From Visual Basic 6.0 too, but While Using that Procedure from SSRS report it shows an error at the Pivot Expression. Following are the Screen Shots, Please Review and Suggest me an Idea.

Here is an Stored Procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[S_NRB_9_8_REPORT](@SCRCODE AS VARCHAR(20),
                                     @CUREDATE VARCHAR(10),
                                     @DTNAME VARCHAR(50),
                                     @BR_CODE VARCHAR(50),
                                     @CENTRALIZED VARCHAR(3))
WITH RECOMPILE
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @BRCODE VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @DTBASE VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @CAT_TYPE_CODE VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @CODESTR VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @CODESTR1 VARCHAR (1000)

SET @BRCODE=''
SET @DTBASE=''
SET @AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME=''
SET @CODESTR=''
SET @CODESTR1=''

SELECT TOP 1 @CAT_TYPE_CODE=CAT_TYPE_CODE FROM REPORT_CAT_TYPE_CODE WHERE SCREEN_CODE =@SCRCODE

IF @CAT_TYPE_CODE='' OR @CAT_TYPE_CODE IS NULL
    RETURN

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#TEMPACTYPE](
    [BR_CODE] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [CN] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BAL] decimal(18, 2) NULL,
    [AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


IF LEN(@BR_CODE)>0
    EXEC('DECLARE CUR INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR SELECT BR_CODE FROM '+@DTBASE+'.DBO.BRANCH B (NOLOCK) WHERE BR_CODE='''+@BR_CODE+''' AND INTEGRATED=''YES'' AND APPROVED=''YES'' ORDER BY BR_CODE')
ELSE
    EXEC('DECLARE CUR INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR SELECT BR_CODE FROM '+@DTBASE+'.DBO.BRANCH B (NOLOCK) WHERE INTEGRATED=''YES'' AND APPROVED=''YES'' ORDER BY BR_CODE')

OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @BRCODE
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    Begin 
        IF @CENTRALIZED='YES'
            SET @DTBASE = @DTNAME
        ELSE
            SET @DTBASE = Left(@DTNAME, 13) + @BRCODE

        EXEC('INSERT INTO #TEMPACTYPE 
             SELECT '''+@BRCODE+''' AS BR_CODE,T1.CAT_NAME AS CN,T1.CODES AS CS,SUM(T1.C_BAL)AS BAL,T1.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME FROM 
                (SELECT C_BAL,ATST.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME,CD.CAT_NAME,CD.CODE_STRING AS CODES
                  FROM 
                       (SELECT AC_GROUP_CODE,CUR_CODE,GL_CODE FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_GROUP_GL_MAP WHERE NAMED_AC_CODE =''0301'') MAP,
                       (SELECT AC_GROUP_CODE,CUR_CODE,AC_NO FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.DEPOSIT_AC_MAST WHERE BR_CODE='''+@BRCODE+''') DAM,
                       (SELECT TRAN_DATE,AC_NO,GL_CODE,PRODUCT_CODE,SUM(CLS_BAL) AS C_BAL FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_BAL WHERE BR_CODE='''+@BRCODE+''' GROUP BY TRAN_DATE,AC_NO,GL_CODE,PRODUCT_CODE) WD,
                       (SELECT * FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.CAT_CODING where BR_CODE='''+@BRCODE+''' AND CAT_TYPE_CODE ='''+@CAT_TYPE_CODE+''') AS CC,
                       (SELECT * FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE) AS ATST,
                       (SELECT * FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_GROUP) AS AG,
                       (SELECT * FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.CAT_DETL) AS CD
                  WHERE
                       DAM.AC_GROUP_CODE =MAP.AC_GROUP_CODE
                       AND DAM.CUR_CODE =MAP.CUR_CODE 
                       AND WD.GL_CODE =MAP.GL_CODE
                       AND CC.ENTITY_NO=DAM.AC_NO
                       AND ATST.AC_TYPE_CODE=AG.AC_TYPE_CODE
                       AND ATST.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_CODE=AG.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_CODE
                       AND AG.AC_GROUP_CODE=DAM.AC_GROUP_CODE
                       AND CD.CAT_TYPE_CODE=CC.CAT_TYPE_CODE
                       AND CD.CAT_CODE=CC.CAT_CODE
                       AND CD.CAT_TYPE_CODE='''+@CAT_TYPE_CODE+'''
                       AND WD.TRAN_DATE = (SELECT MAX(TRAN_DATE) FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_BAL WHERE BR_CODE ='''+@BRCODE+''' AND AC_NO = DAM.AC_NO AND TRAN_DATE <='''+@CUREDATE+''' AND GL_CODE=MAP.GL_CODE)
                       AND DAM.AC_NO=WD.AC_NO
                  UNION ALL
                        SELECT 0,ATST.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME,CAT_NAME,CODE_STRING AS CODES FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.CAT_DETL AS CD,'+@DTBASE+'.dbo.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE AS ATST
                        WHERE CAT_TYPE_CODE='''+@CAT_TYPE_CODE+''' AND CAT_CODE NOT IN (SELECT CAT_CODE FROM '+@DTBASE+'.dbo.CAT_CODING WHERE BR_CODE='''+@BRCODE+''' AND CAT_TYPE_CODE='''+@CAT_TYPE_CODE+''')
                        AND ATST.AC_TYPE_CODE=''03''
                        ) T1 
                  GROUP BY T1.AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME,CAT_NAME,CODES
                  ORDER BY CODES
               ')
        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @BRCODE
    END
DEALLOCATE CUR

DECLARE CUR INSENSITIVE CURSOR FOR  SELECT DISTINCT AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME FROM #TEMPACTYPE
OPEN CUR
Fetch Next from CUR Into @AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    Begin 
        IF @CODESTR ='' 
            BEGIN
                SET @CODESTR =  'ISNULL(['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+'],0) AS ['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+']'
                SET @CODESTR1 =  '['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+']' 
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @CODESTR = @CODESTR+',ISNULL(['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+'],0) AS ['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+']'
                SET @CODESTR1 = @CODESTR1+',['+@AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME+']'
            END

        Fetch Next from CUR Into @AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME
    END
DEALLOCATE CUR

EXEC ('Select CS,CN,'+@CODESTR+',TOTAL 
       from (Select CN,CS,BAL,[AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME] from #TEMPACTYPE) ps pivot (SUM([BAL])
       for [AC_TYPE_SUB_TYPE_NAME]  in ('+@CODESTR1+',TOTAL)) pvt
       Order by CS')
DROP TABLE #TEMPACTYPE
END
GO
```

And, the Dataset Design Panel :
[image]

But, Stored Procedure Runs Well inside SSMS :

[image]

Im Using SSRS 2008 R2.

Please Help me out.
And, Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try validating that you are passing the same parameter values between the report and SSMS.  You can do this by clicking Edit Query and inputting the actual parameter values.  If the Edit Query window returns proper results, then you are probably passing different values to the stored procedure.

Comment: I'd tried 4-5 times in SSRS and SSMS too. I even Copy and Paste the values. But didnt worked.

Comment: When you run the query from the Edit Query window, do you also get the same error?

Comment: Have you tried pasting in the EXEC S_NRB_9_8_REPORT '11224','9/1/2011','INFINITY_002_019','019','NO' as the query so that the parameters for the report are essentially ignored?  The goal here is to validate whether or not SSRS can even execute this successfully.